# Arrows showing Extent of multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I am creating a table with different `multirow` heights.  I would like arrows that extend above/below the text to show the extent to which the `multirow` applies.  A naive example is below with the desired arrows in red.

[image: Arrows with multrow]

A hackish solution is possible for three rows (see black arrows), but it would be ideal if there was a way automatically create the arrows regardless of the number of rows.

The table in the MWE is simple enough it could be drawn entirely with `tikz`, but the intended application makes a complete `tikz` implementation impractical.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
      \toprule
      1 & \multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{4}{*}{+}     & $\uparrow$ \\\cline{1-1}
      2 &                    &                        & Z   \\\cline{1-2}
      3 & \multirow{2}{*}{B} &                        & $\downarrow$ \\\cline{1-1}\cline{4-4}
      4 &                    &                        & $\uparrow$ \\\cline{1-3}
      5 & \multirow{2}{*}{C} & \multirow{2}{*}{+}     & Z   \\\cline{1-1}
      6 &                    &                        & $\downarrow$ \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not apply shading to multirows

Answer (score 3):

Why is a TikZ solution impractical?
Here is a solution with a TikZ matrix, it can be easily extended with any number of rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering 
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={text height=3ex, text depth=1ex, text width=2em, text centered}] (mymatr)
      {  
      1&&&\\
      2&&&\\
      3&&&\\
      4&&&\\
      5&&&\\
      6&&&\\
      };
      % Horizontal lines
      \draw[thick] (mymatr-1-1.north west) -- (mymatr-1-4.north east);
      \foreach \ind in {1,3,5} 
        {\draw[thick] (mymatr-\ind-1.south west) --       (mymatr-\ind-1.south east);}
      \draw[thick] (mymatr-2-1.south west) -- (mymatr-2-2.south east);
      \draw[thick] (mymatr-3-4.south west) -- (mymatr-3-4.south east);
      \draw[thick] (mymatr-4-1.south west) -- (mymatr-4-3.south east);
      \draw[thick] (mymatr-6-1.south west) -- (mymatr-6-4.south east);
      % Vertical lines
      \draw[red, {Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-1-2.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{A} (mymatr-2-2.south);
      \draw[red, {Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-3-2.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{B} (mymatr-4-2.south);
      \draw[red, {Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-5-2.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{C} (mymatr-6-2.south);
      \draw[red, {Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-1-3.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{+} (mymatr-4-3.south);
      \draw[red, {Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-5-3.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{+} (mymatr-6-3.south);
      \draw[{Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-1-4.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{Z} (mymatr-3-4.south);
      \draw[{Latex}-{Latex}] (mymatr-4-4.north) -- node[fill=white, text=black]{Z} (mymatr-6-4.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]